# Is there any way to delete the default text entered into the entry widget when the user click on the entry widget

Tags: tkinter

I need a help, i set a default text in the tkinter entry widget. What i need is, the default text need to be cleared automatically once the user click on the entry widget to enter the input.

Comment: Do you only want to remove it when the user clicks, or also if they use the tab key to set focus to the widget? In either case, this might be _very_ frustrating for the user. What if they type something and then want to select it (requiring a click), or want to edit it after the fact?

Answer (score 3):

Every time the entry is clicked it will clear the previous contents. Whether it be from the default stringvar value or the previous text the user entered.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

myvar = tk.StringVar()
myvar.set("A test")

def on_click(event):

    event.widget.delete(0, tk.END)

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=myvar)
entry.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Adding `event.widget.bindu("<Button-1>")` to `on_click` will make this behaviour only occur on the first click.

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes care of both focus in and click events and tests for default text so no other text is deleted on click or focus in.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def on_click(event):
    ent2.config(foreground='black')
    if ent2.get() == "Click & type...":
        event.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
    else:
        ent2.config(foreground='black')

myvar = tk.StringVar()
myvar.set("Click & type...")

ent1 = ttk.Entry(root)
ent1.grid()

ent2 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=myvar)
ent2.config(foreground='gray')
ent2.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
ent2.bind("<FocusIn>", on_click)
ent2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```